# Can a Swift function accept only a range of values?

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift3, uiimage

What I am trying to do is write a generic function that compresses the image.

```
func compress(image: UIImage, withRatio ratio: CGFloat) -> Data? {
    return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, ratio)
}
```

But here the `compress()`'s `ratio` can be any `CGFloat` value `0...∞`, but I want to accept only `0.0...1.0`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: do you want a Swift `Range` as a parameter or do you want to pass along start / end values in an array parameter (such as like what one can do when creating gradients)?

Comment: NO, you cannot represent such constraint in the current type system of Swift. You can just put a runtime check using `assert` or similar functions.

Comment: you can use `precondition(0.0...1.0 ~= ratio)`

Answer (score 2):

As your function already can return `nil`, you can check the value of `ratio` before using it. If it is not in your desired range, you can return `nil`.

```
func compress(image: UIImage, withRatio ratio: CGFloat) -> Data? {
    if 0...1 ~= ratio {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, ratio)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Or you can throw an exception:

```
enum CompressError: Error {
    case ratioOutOfRange
}

func compress(image: UIImage, withRatio ratio: CGFloat) throws -> Data? {
    if 0...1 ~= ratio {
        return UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, ratio)
    } else {
        throw CompressError.ratioOutOfRange
    }
}
```